# Record Login Date/time

Tags: c#, identityserver4

We are using IdentityServer 4 as our login server, in conjunction with Web API 2.0 and Angular 5.

I have been asked to record the date and time that users log in, which doesn't seem too unreasonable. IdentityServer 4 doesn't do this by default.

I thought the most sensible thing to do would be to add a LoginTime column to the AspNetUsers table and a corresponding property to the ApplicationUser class, then I could just set this during the login process. I can't change the actual login code as this takes place in the `UserManager` class but I thought I could add my own additional code, for example in the controller method, or an abstraction of it anyway.

But, I can't seem to trap the login endpoint call. I have breakpoints everywhere and none of them are being hit, and anyway none seem to have a signature matching the data being posted. The dev tools in Chrome tell me that the call looks like it's going to 'roughly' the right place, but I'm beginning to think that the endpoint itself is embedded in the API somewhere I don't have access to.

I guess it's possible that this is a config option, but if so I can't find out which one.

This being the case, how can I extend the login method to record the date and time? I have searched online to find how to extend the login process but can't find it anywhere.

This needs to be done at the same time as the authentication token is created. A second call from the client could in theory be bypassed and this would not be good.

I was going to post some code here as I know it'll probably be asked for, but it doesn't seem relevant as I can't find the right endpoint anyway!

How can I extend the login endpoint to save the date and time users log in?

Comment: I thought Identity Server abstracted the default Asp.Net User tables, because the underlying code implemented is straight up bizarre.

Comment: Yes it does, but the online docs say you can extend `AspNetUsers` by adding a property to your abstraction, in my case `ApplicationUser`

Comment: If you're using the default template for ASP.NET Core Identity, the actual logging in process will be handled using the `SignInManager` ([`PasswordSignInAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.passwordsigninasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_SignInManager_1_PasswordSignInAsync__0_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_) et al), not the `UserManager`. The `SignInManager` really just sits on top of the `UserManager`, so you can implement your own sign-in code and customise the process rather easily.

Comment: You could also use the approach as seen in the [samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity/src/IdentityServerWithAspNetIdentity/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L103), where a `UserLoginSuccessEvent` is raised in the Quickstart. You could either handle this event or put your own code inline, depending on your preference.

Comment: My main problem is that the end-point shown in that example isn't being called. I have break-points on all the actions in the `AccountController` and none are hit during login.

Comment: In which case, you are likely already logged in to Identity Server (more accurately, ASP.NET Core Identity). There's a difference between logging in and issuing a token.